# How to determine the most important variables when there are differences in variable importance between predictive models

Tags: predictive-models, causality, boosting, glmnet, importance

**Background:**

I am running predictive models to see which variables have the most influence over a chosen measurement. In this example I am comparing the models `gbm` and `glmnet`.

After training both models, I compare their performances by looking at the RMSE and R-squared values. In this example, `glmnet` looks best. However, comparing them statistically shows that the models are not significantly different.

When I then look at the variable importance for each model using the `varImp()` function, they show a different order of variables. This is not so pronounced in the `iris` dataset in this example, since it only has 3 variables, however my true data has many variables, and the order of their importance is vastly different between the two models.

**Code:**

```r
library(caret)
library(glmnet)
library(gbm)
library(dplyr)

data(iris)
set.seed(100)

## partition for test and train at 80% train
samp     <- createDataPartition(iris$Sepal.Length, p=0.8, list=FALSE) 
training <- iris[samp,]
testing  <- iris[-samp,]


## Set up the resampling, here repeated CV
tr <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=5)   

## glmnet training model
glmnet_model <- train(Sepal.Length ~ ., data = dplyr::select(training, -Species), 
                      preProcess = c("center", "scale"),
                      method = "glmnet", trControl = tr)   

## Use expand grid to create a table of all possible combinations for gbm model
tg <- expand.grid(shrinkage = seq(0.1, 1, by = 0.2), 
                  interaction.depth = c(1, 3, 7, 10),
                  n.minobsinnode = c(2, 5, 10),
                  n.trees = c(100, 300, 500, 1000))

## gbm training model
gbm_model <- train(Sepal.Length ~ ., data=dplyr::select(training, -Species), 
                   method="gbm", trControl=tr, tuneGrid=tg, verbose=FALSE)

## Visually inspect the results table with resamples(). 
##  The best model has the lowest RMSE and the highest R-squared
mods <- resamples(list(elasticnet=glmnet_model, gbm=gbm_model))

## glmnet looks best
summary(mods) 
## but they are not significantly different (p-value = 0.07029)
compare_models(glmnet_model, gbm_model) 

##### Relative influences of variables

## glmnet variable importance
varImp(glmnet_model) 
# Overall
# Petal.Length 100.000
# Petal.Width    8.718
# Sepal.Width    0.000

## gbm variable importance
varImp(gbm_model) 
# Overall
# Petal.Length 100.000
# Sepal.Width    3.283
# Petal.Width    0.000
```

With my results I would like to be able to tell a client what the most important variables are for determining their desired outcome. In this example, a client wanted to know what are the key determinants of Sepal length in iris flowers. I would like to run the model and be able to say 'Petal length is the greatest determinant of Sepal length. If one would like to maximise Sepal Length (for profitability), they should focus on Petal length as a priority, followed by....(additional variables in order of importance)'. So I guess what I am asking is ***why*** are the results between the models different? That way I can make an informed decision about which to choose.

Comment: I think it's important to consider the *goal* here, which is unclear in the question. 'Should I go with the order of whichever model performed best' is a bit hard to answer if we don't know what is being done with the variable importance ranking subsequently.

Comment: @mkt I have updated my question. Thanks for the interest.

Comment: There are several (very) different ways of determining "what's an important determinant" in a regression, but the link to "what should you do to increase profitability" is something you have to be very careful about - if the relationship you observed between $x$ and $y$ is not causal, then manipulating $x$ may not turn out to have the desired effect on $y$. Also, from a profit point of view, one must also consider the *costs* of manipulating each $x$ variable.

Comment: @Silverfish I understand what you are saying. I have updated my question again. Could you please explain why the two models give different results?

Comment: I'm not an expert on `gbm` or `glmnet` but it is worth clarifying what you mean by "variable importance" since there are many different ways this can be measured. I understand you are making use of the `varImp` function, but [this function does different things on different types of models](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-80/topics/varImp). You might find it helpful to decide whether you want to ask about "variable importance" in general terms, or if your question is about the specific measure of importance that `varImp` applies in your case.